# Using groupby function properly

Tags: pandas, python-2.7, dataframe, group-by

I have a dataframe called df1 which looks like this:

```
details                endFrame id  indexID object  startFrame
List of dictionaries 1   1111   78    0    Motorbike    1
List of dictionaries 2   3647   78    0    Motorbike    1112
List of dictionaries 3   3678   78    0    Motorbike    3649
List of dictionaries 4   704    120   3    Pedestrian   66
List of dictionaries 5   817    120   3    Pedestrian   705
List of dictionaries 6   922    141   5    Car          818
```

The list of dictionaries look like this:

```
[{'y2': 627, 'frame': 1, 'visibility': 0, 'y1': 603, 'score': 1, 'x2': 770, 'x1': 759, 'class': 1}, {'y2': 623, 'frame': 2, 'visibility': 0, 'y1': 599, 'score': 1, 'x2': 777, 'x1': 766, 'class': 1},....]
```

What I am trying to do is to merge the rows that have the same indexID together. Also, I would have to extend each list of dictionaries to become one long list instead of having multiple lists in the 'details' cell. In other words, once merged, the details cell would have a very long list of dictionaries.

I do not need to bother about what happens in the 'endframe', 'id' and 'startframe' columns in df1. However, eached merged indexID must still have an Object. Note that each row of the same indexID in df1 will alwas have the same object.

Sample output:

```
details                       endFrame  id  indexID object  startFrame
List of dictionaries 1,2 and 3   1111   78    0    Motorbike    1
List of dictionaries 4 and 5      704   120   3    Pedestrian   66
List of dictionaries 6            922   141   5    Car          818
```

Comment: It would be better if you can provide a sample output.

Comment: @dataLeo thanks for the suggestion. I have included it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
_newdf2 = df1.groupby('indexID')['detail'].sum().reset_index()
        for index,row in _newdf2.iterrows():
            x = _newdf.loc[df1['indexID'] == row['indexID'], 'object']
            _newdf2['object'] = x.to_string().lstrip('0123456789.- ')
```